# Yaesu VX-8DE bricked after cloning. Any methods to revive it?

Tags: ht, yaesu, equipment-troubleshooting

I seem to have bricked my VX-8DE yesterday after cloning it from a PC (using CHIRP)

I was able to copy the data from the radio without problems. I edited it in chirp, then sent it back to the radio. After cloning was finished the VX-8 restarted and started to behave in a strange manner. It was barely reacting to any input (be it keyboard or knob). The VFO A display showed something along the lines of `b1 30.303`, which I suppose might have been an error message of some kind, but I wasn't able to find any reference to it. The VFO B was set to the frequency I set it to before cloning and I wasn't able to change it by turning the knob. After a while the radio stopped reacting to the input entirely so I removed and reconnected the battery. Since then I wasn't able to power the radio on.

I tried to enter both microprocessor reset mode (BAND+HM/RV+Internet+Power) and the set reset mode (BAND+V/M+Power) but they won't power on the radio either. When I connect the radio to the charger it doesn't show anything on the screen and the busy LED which normally indicates the charging status doesn't lit up either.

My question is, has this happened to anyone else, and if yes were they able to get the radio working on their own? Mine is still covered by the warranty, so I'll be posting it to the local distributor on Monday, but until then I could try other options, if anyone knows of any.

Comment: Back in the day, Yaesu was easy to approach for technical advice.  I'm not sure if that is still true, but it would be a good idea to try out.

Comment: If they were easy to approach then, they should now have _paid_ support engineers browse this site (and, possibly, other similar forums) answering people's questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radio came back from the Yaesu's dealer today. My warranty card now has an entry stating 'hardware processor reset'. It seems they had to open the radio to do whatever had to be done. In other words: it seems that in case like this there is nothing you can do on your own, and you're better off giving your HT to professionals.

An interesting tidbit here is that according to the technician handling the radio the battery was completely drained out, despite it being freshly charged when this issue happened. So apparently it was still drawing current even though it appeared to be dead. If anything like this happens to you, you might want to disconnect the battery before shipping your radio for repairs.

Answer (score 0):

The correct sequence is

1. Turn the radio off
2. Hold down the Band, HM/RV, and TX PO buttons (3 buttons)
3. Turn the power on
4. Release the three buttons
5. Press the FW key briefly

If this doesn't work, it is typically due to not holding down all three buttons at once. Try a different finger pattern.

Comment: Hi @Glenn thanks for your answer. I'm pretty sure I've been trying this correctly. My radio has been at Yaesu's dealer for several weeks now, and just today I got an information that they have been able to bring it up using "very deep hardware reset" which is "not a usual procedure". In other words I must have had the baddest of lucks.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it resolved. Hopefully it doesn't happen again!